# Drupal front page blog entries custom sort order

Tags: 7

I have two blog entries which as defaults displays in front page.

1.) Submitted by admin on Thu, 06/16/2016 - 13:32 displays second
2.) Submitted by admin on Thu, 06/16/2016 - 13:33 displays first

I would like to display these at any point of time in a custom order, probably using custom field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add your custom field "sort_order" to the blog content type, then create a page view (/admin/structure/views/add) for the blog content (just like node does it in the "frontpage" view - you may even copy that view and restrict the nodetype to blog in your copy).

Then change the "sort criteria" in the view to your sort_order custom field.

Then you're done.